# What damage occurs in an ESP32 when you power it with 5V

Tags: esp8266, component-failure

A colleague flashed the PIC MCUs on a batch of boards. However he didn't pay attention to set the Vdd when programming to 3.3V and used the default (5V). This caused the ESP32 on board to experience 5V briefly. The 5V was supplied via a PicKit3.

Now the ESP32 datasheet specifically says 3.6V being the absolute maximum supply voltage.

The chips seem to be still working fine, as far as I can tell. The problem is that I don't know what to test more specifically - what kind of damage occurs in a chip that isn't 5V-tolerant? Anyone with some experience with this part and this kind of misuse?

I know that the usual answer to this type of questions is "if it's outside the datasheet specs, all bets are off", and if it were a board or two, I'd just shrug it off, but it's a whole batch which I don't want to write off unless *absolutely* necessary.

Comment: if it's one off for your hobby use, I'd say just use it. If you're selling these things to other people, for money, and warranting service, then I think you already know the answer.

Comment: Do you have any devices limiting the current to the ESP32 or limiting the voltage? I'm not familiar with the PicKit3 and what current it can supply. It could be that you are still fine because the current wasn't enough to damage anything. The damage and the way it manifests itself can be very random and you'd have to do a full specification test to really see if something got damaged. And even then you might run into long term reliability issues.

Comment: The PicKit3 should limit the output current to around 30mA.